# Error deleting a publication

Tags: sql-server, replication

I am trying to remove replication on my development workstation. Here is the error I get:

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Could not delete publication 'PublicationName'.

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.0.1600.22&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.Replication.ReplicationMenuItem&EvtID=CantDeletePublication&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------

Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'MyDomain\MyUserName', error code 0x5.
Changed database context to 'OLTPDatabase'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15404)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.00.2531&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=15404&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

How do I start debugging this?

Answer (score 3):

Error 5 is access denied.  In this case the SQL Server is having problems verifying your domain credentials when trying to run a query.  I would assume the query in question is trying to talk to one of the other SQL Servers in the replication topology and perhaps you don't have access to it.  The network share where the snapshot is stored perhaps?

Comment: it turned out to be the owner of the Primary Database for replication was causing this issue. I changed the owner and was able to proceed from there.

Comment: What was the owner set to?

Comment: @MrDenny: Funnily enough it was set to my own login. MyDomain\MyUserName.  The database is generated from a Visual Studio 2008 project. I changed the owner to SA to fix this.

Comment: That's just strange.  I assume your account has sysadmin rights since you are making changes to replication.  No idea what the root cause could be.  I'd have to muck with it and see exactly where the error was happening in the process to give a more firm answer as to why.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a million. I also just changed the db owner of the published database to be sa rather than my windows account, and it did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried taking the database offline, then removing?